# Yii2 Model vs FormModel

Tags: yii2

I am looking for explanation and use cases for the situation I should use 
`FormModel` instead of `Model`

Let's put up an example, the classic `Author` class

```
class Author extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'tbl_author';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id'], 'integer'],
        [['name'], 'string', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 64],
        [['name'], 'required'],
        [['age'], 'integer'],
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => Yii::t('message', 'ID'),
        'name' => Yii::t('message', 'Name'),
        'age' => Yii::t('message', 'Age'),
    ];
}

public function getBook() 
{
  return $this->hasMany(Book::className(), ['id' => 'id_book'])->via('author_book_relation');
}

public function getAuthorBook()
{
  return $this->hasMany(AuthorBook::className(), ['id_author' => 'id']);
}
}
```

Pretty regular model.
An `Author` with an `id`, `name` and `age` attributes , which has relations to his `Books`, via the relation table `AuthorBook`.

For the pseudo class `AuthorForm` that this question is about, I suppose to have to use it in the `actionCreate` and `actionUpdate`.

Am I always supposed to use it for every type of `Model` that requires a UserInterface to be inserted/updated ?

What is the real purpose of `AuthorForm` ?

Letting me have a `Mode`l made only for those 2 cases (`actionCreate`, `actionUpdate`) which can be dirtied as I wish, without having to worry about the "real" model which handles the data itself?
Letting me specify some "support variables" for a form view, where I could (for example) define the relation `AuthorBook`?

Comment: Use the form model to validate user submitted data using the form. If the form is valid pass the data to your model. That's a typical scenario.

Comment: With the term FormModel you refer  to model not based an activeRecord ? explain better .. because the FormModel .. is  a bit ambiguos

Comment: @scaisEdge the quickest example I have right now is from the docs :
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html#activerecord-based-forms-activeform
With FormModel I mean a class ( AuthorForm ) extending my base ActiveRecord class ( Author )

Comment: I have posted  some words  about your question .. hope are useful

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking in MVC,  Models and FormModels express two different concepts .. The first (Model) defines all classes who care to manage common attributes and methods regardless of their representation (view) and regardless of the application correlations (controller) .. Often the term model is also synonymous of  active records,  that is a model directly related to the modeling of data for its preservation in a database or retrieval syste, while the term FormModel is primarly addressed to the management  of information "container"  not directly related to dabatabase or carrying out a brokerage function between the storage requirements and the needs of the data acquisition ..  in this sense the Form that is a typical data acquisition model is modeled in a (FormModel) so as to facilitate these operations.

Therefore frequently it is using a FormModel in those cases where the need to acquire or maintain a given entity is the applicant and therefore favors the use of common components for the purposes of greater reusability and consistency.

This is a theoretical Then ..in practice is helpful to use a FormModel every time you are faced with data structures, methods of access and ricorrennte validation rules. A recurring case is that of FormModel for creating the change .. with one classa are handled more

..Hope this is useful